# "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host" - only on online server (works on localhost)

Tags: email, smtp

in order to activate SMTP service i used following code in class.user.php
it works fine when i'm connected to localhost, however, i received this error when i'm connected to actual server
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

```
<?php  
require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                      
$mail->Host       = "mail.*****.de";
$mail->Port       = 465;             
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Username="***********";             
$mail->Password="**************";
$mail->SetFrom('arastu@al***b.com','Almas Web SetForm');
$mail->AddReplyTo("arastu@al***b.com","Almas Web Addreply to");
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->Send();
}   
}
?>
```

Please let me know what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it works with your local host, and not with an external SMTP server, it's most likely that :

- either your externel SMTP server address is invalid
- or a firewall is blocking your connection

Try to telnet your external SMTP server port (for example, using [putty](http://www.putty.org)). If the connection works, the issue is within your code, else, it's within your network infrastructure, or your smtp server address is invalid. To confirm the latter, repeat your test from a different network.

Comment: Nicolas, the difference between local connection and server connection is only database information. I donot changed the SMTP server info for local host and it works fine with it. I also tested the process while firewall was off and still have the issue.